# How can I display data from multiple entities in same view and group them by one of the entity

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have clients, projects, client comments and project comments. I want to display one table grouped by client followed by all projects and for each client where there is a comment as well as for each project that has a comment display the last provided comment.

The table would have the Client Name at the top followed by the latest respective comment if provided. 
It would be followed by the list of all projects for that client with their latest comment if provided.

I have the client model:

```
    public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ClientComment> ClientComments { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

The project model:

```
    public class Project
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public bool IsArchived { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProjectComment> ProjectComments { get; set; }
```

The client comment model:

```
    public class ClientComment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public string StatusComment { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public ClientComment ()
        {
            this.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
```

The project comment model:

```
    public class ProjectComment
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }

        public string StatusComment { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public ProjectComment ()
        {
            this.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
```

The end result should be with their respective table headers:

```
ClientName1    | ClientStatusComment
ProjectName1   | ProjectStatusComment
ProjectName2   | ProjectStatusComment
ProjectName3   | ProjectStatusComment

ClientName2    | ClientStatusComment
ProjectName1   | ProjectStatusComment
ProjectName2   | ProjectStatusComment
ProjectName3   | ProjectStatusComment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use View Model which contains the properties you need display in the view.Refer to as follows:

1. `ClientVM` and `ProjectVM`

   ```
   public class ClientVM
   {
     public string ClientName { get; set; }
     public string ClientStatusComment { get; set; }
     public List<ProjectVM> Projectlist { get; set; }
   }

   public class ProjectVM
   {
     public string ProjectName { get; set; }
     public string ProjectStatusComment { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Populate the ViewModel

   ```
   public class ClientsDetailsModel : PageModel
   {
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public ClientsDetailsModel(MyDbContext context)
   {
       _context = context;
   } 

   [BindProperty]
   public List<ClientVM> clientVMList { get; set; }

   public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
   {
       var clientlist = _context.Clients
           .Include(c => c.ClientComments)
           .Include(c => c.Projects)
               .ThenInclude(p => p.ProjectComments).ToList();

       clientVMList = new List<ClientVM>();

       foreach (var item in clientlist)
       {
           ClientVM clientVM = new ClientVM()
           {
               Projectlist = new List<ProjectVM>()
           };
           clientVM.ClientName = item.ClientName;
           if (item.ClientComments != null && item.ClientComments.Any())
           {
               clientVM.ClientStatusComment = item.ClientComments.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.LastUpdateDate).First().StatusComment;
           }
           else
           {
               clientVM.ClientStatusComment = "No StatusComment";
           }
           foreach (var projectItem in item.Projects)
           {
               ProjectVM projectVM = new ProjectVM();
               projectVM.ProjectName = projectItem.ProjectName;
               if (projectItem.ProjectComments != null && projectItem.ProjectComments.Any())
               {
                   projectVM.ProjectStatusComment = projectItem.ProjectComments.OrderByDescending(pc => pc.LastUpdateDate).First().StatusComment;
               }
               else
               {
                   projectVM.ProjectStatusComment = "No StatusComment";
               }
               clientVM.Projectlist.Add(projectVM);
           }

           clientVMList.Add(clientVM);
       }

       return Page();
    }
   }
   ```
3. ClientsDetails.cshtml

   ```
   @page
   @model MultipleEntitiesInSameView.Pages.ClientsDetailsModel

   <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>
               Name
           </th>
           <th>
               LastStatusComment
           </th>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach (var item in Model.clientVMList)
       {
           <tr style="background-color:aliceblue;">
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientName)

               </td>

               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientStatusComment)
               </td>
           </tr>
           @foreach (var projectItem in item.Projectlist)
           {
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => projectItem.ProjectName)

                   </td>

                   <td>
                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => projectItem.ProjectStatusComment)
                   </td>
               </tr>

           }
       }
    </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

4.Result :
[image]

Comment: Thank you very clear solution. However, I have one issue with the code. I get the following error: CS0103 The name 'View' does not exist in the current context. I use Visual Studio 2019 if this helps troubleshooting.

Comment: My mistake , this is a demo with MVC . I have updated the demo with Razor pages , you could check my edit on PageModel and the ClientsDetails page